# SQL query to clean up/omit missing values depending on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a query that is able to omit certain values (which are missing in another table). Trying to explain it using an example:

Table 1 - Person

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane |
| 2 | Joe |
| 3 | Jose |

Table 2 - Schedule

| Date | Employees |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | Jane,Joe,Jose |
| 2/1 | Alice,Jane |
| 3/1 | Joe,Bob,Jose |
| 4/1 | Alice,Bob |

Expected result - missing values omitted

| Date | Employees |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | Jane,Joe,Jose |
| 2/1 | Jane |
| 3/1 | Joe,Jose |
| 4/1 |  |

Is that even possible to achieve with SQL, and if so, how?

Disclaimer: I do not have any impact on the design of the tables. I know that the structure is far from ideal, but there is no way to change it.

Comment: You should not have such a table in the first place. Don't store multiple values in the same column. This violates database normalization (first normal form). Change the schedule table to have one date and employee per row.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Please take the time and read the full description (-> Disclaimer), thank you.

Comment: Is the data type string array or a string?

Comment: @GibreelAbdullah, the data type is string (varchar2)

Comment: Ah, I should have read to the end :-) Sorry. So, what is your actual problem with writing the query? Don't you know how to split the employees string? Don't you know how to concatenate the names again? What have you tried and where have you got stuck?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I think my problem was to not consider a recursive query to split the string :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a normalized schedule table. You can create that on-the-fly with a recursive query or a combination of a lateral cross join and unnesting an array that you create from the substrings. Put this in a CTE (`WITH` clause) and then do your aggregation.

### With an array and UNNEST

```
with good_schedule as
(
  select s.date, e.employee_name
  from schedule s
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(employees, ',')) as e(employee_name)
)
select s.date, string_agg(p.name, ',' order by p.name) as employees
from good_schedule s
left outer join person p on p.name = s.employee_name
group by s.date
order by s.date;
```

### With a recursive CTE

```
with recursive good_schedule(date, employees, employee_name, pos) as
(
  select date, employees, split_part(employees, ',', 1), 1
  from schedule s
  union all
  select date, employees, split_part(employees, ',', pos+1) as employee_name, pos+1
  from good_schedule
  where split_part(employees, ',', pos+1) <> ''
)
select s.date, string_agg(p.name, ',' order by p.name) as employees
from good_schedule s
left outer join person p on p.name = s.employee_name
group by s.date
order by s.date;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/A42E5oYh

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, thank you. I'm using the CTE version.